# How to load value to text field when choose value in select

Tags: php, html, css

I have problem need help that, I have a form have 1 select filed and 1 text field, I want when I choose value in option of select the text field will load/appear value in proportion to value of select, example in picture when I choose "B" in select field, the value in text filed will appear "1", so how to do it, I need example to refer, guide or demo example, Thank for read my topic.

Here is Image

```
http://i1095.photobucket.com/albums/i472/OLAKEN91/gdf_zpsac464e04.jpg
```

Code:

```
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <br />
    <form id="cv" action="" method="">
        Choose Option: <select id="chedo">
        <option>--Choose Value--</option>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        Value: <input type="text" id="lenh" size="40"/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
    </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/ Also why is php tagged in this?

Comment: you must add a value attribute at you option tag, after you can catch the change event on the select tag, you can thus get the value selected and put them on you imput by using what @TreeTree says

Answer (score 1):

If you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you can use a combination of the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler and the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function. Both have been linked to documentation with examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript/jQuery to do this.

```
$("#chedo").change(function(){
    var selected = $("#chedo").val();
    $("#lenh").val(selected);
});
```

shorter:

```
$("#chedo").change(function(){
    $("#lenh").val($(this).val());
});
```

Also your options must have a value:

```
<option value="0">A</option>
<option value="1">B</option>
<option value="2">C</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best best is to use jQuery

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tWPC/)

```
$('#chedo').change(function () {
    $('#lenh').val($(this)[0].selectedIndex - 1);
})
```